# Mark package as installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, packages, apt, dpkg

I've manually compiled openssl and ofcourse it works. Apt does not see the package as being installed.

After that i've been trying to download stuff using wget. Everytime when i tried downloading from a https-source it gave me a message complaining about how certificates of some sort where missing. Apparently package *ca-certificates* was missing. I was trying to install it with *apt-get install ca-certificates*. But when i did that, it also wanted to install the dependency openssl. I Aborted because i didnt want to overwrite my own install of openssl.

Finally i chose for *apt-get download ca-certificates* and *dpkg -i ca-certificates.deb* and wget was working again.

Everytime im trying to install something, apt is complaining about how dependencies where not met.

I was trying to mark openssl as being installed using *apt-mark manual openssl* however, somehow its still looking for a installation of some sort before its added to the list.

The reason im making this such a long story is because im not entirely sure my approach was the right one.

Should i also compile *ca-certificates*? So i wont get any error messages about unmet dependencies? or is there a way to actually make apt forget about openssl? im looking for a solution and some guidance about what more experienced people would do.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Why did you manually compile openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking a package as installed that is not sounds not like a good idea to me. What about update handling on this? What about patches used by other packages that depend on it.

I'd rather go with the normal installation, add the self-compiled version under /opt and use update-alternatives to point to that if possible.

Comment: That is my problem. I do think my approach is wrong. but what is the right one when people are using a package manager and self-compiled software?

Comment: This is OSS, there is no right way. Just some acceptable ways, more possible ways and maybe a dozen bad habits.